Selenium - wait for element to be enabled
I am trying to scrape a website that has an element that has opacity: 0. This means I can't use element_to_be_clickable since that function checks that an element is enabled and visible since Selenium (rightfully so) assumes that an element with an opacity of 0 is invisible.
The element I am trying to click is (to me) visible.
So as an alternative I would like to wait for the element to be enabled, but I am not sure what wait to use.
I am also open for other strategies.
Thank you.

explicit wait with expected condition of elementToBeClickable: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/  Expected condition: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By)

@browsermator, as I said, i can't use that.

if it does become enabled/visible at some point, that's what you want to use.  The purpose of the wait is to ignore those exceptions for a certain amount of time.  (it keeps polling till timeout or the element is clickable...)

@browsermator i'd like to. It is visible to me, but it's opacity is 0 perpetually, so it never becomes visible to selenium.

I think I'm misunderstanding what "it is visible to me" means.   If you can click on it manually, then you could execute javascript to click it, or use a wait that doesn't check visibility.  Maybe just presenceOf is enough.  The click() method itself might do it's own check, though, and throw the element not clickable at point... exception.

You are right, to me the element is visible, but to selenium it isn't since it's opaciuty is 0.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/14030
I understand why they did it this way, but I still need to find a workaround. I'll probably write my own wait using is_enabled.
